# Append Ajax to an element using createDocumentFragment(); instead of create Element

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, createelement

This post was the most helpfull to understand createDocumentFragment() instead of createElement()
[Should I use document.createDocumentFragment or document.createElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397161/should-i-use-document-createdocumentfragment-or-document-createelement)

I've understood that for performance reason using fragment will help on big dataset so i want to conver my function.

This is what i use right now and it works as desired => Get content from a php file with ajax and then append this content at the **top** of existing `div#wrapper`**inside** a new `div.feedBox`(`r` being the XMLHTTP /ACTIVE OBJECT)

```
r.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(r.readyState==4 && r.status==200){

        //Want to convert this to createDocumentFrangment --START
        var n = document.createElement("div");
        n.className = "feedBox";
        n.innerHTML = r.responseText;
        document.getElementById("wrapper").insertBefore(n, document.getElementById("wrapper").firstChild);
        //Want to convert this to createDocumentFrangment --END
    }
}
```

This is what i tried, but what happens is the content is added but without the div.feedBox

```
var n = document.createElement("div");
n.className = "feedBox";
n.innerHTML = r.responseText;
var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
while (n.firstChild) { f.appendChild(n.firstChild); }
document.getElementById("wrapper").insertBefore(f, document.getElementById("wrapper").firstChild);
```

What did i miss? can you explain why and how to make it work?
Is this really a more efficient way of doing this?

PS: NO jquery please. I know it well and i use it widely on other project but i want this to be as small / lite / efficient as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this line

```
while (n.firstChild) { f.appendChild(n.firstChild);
```

be

```
f.appendChild(n);
```

Also I see that you are not appending the `div.feedBox` to your DOM anywhere..

What happens if the `while condition fails`.. You are not appending anything to your `DOM`..

I am assuming this will work .. Not tested though

```
f.appendChild(n)
document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(f,        
                                 document.getElementById("wrapper").firstChild);
```

ALso better to use

`.appendChild(f,`  **instead of**  `.insertBefore(f,`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9vxG8/)**

Comment: Nothing happend using this the if statemnt. Like i said every thing works great with the code, except that my ajax content is not encapsulated in the div.feedBox. (like it is with the previous version)

Comment: Jkust as a reference, it actually did reduce the function response time. From about 12-15ms to 7-9ms On small dataset.

Comment: Thats cool.. I will try using it the next time I need to do such a thing

Answer (score 0):

This is the full working function, any1 sould feel free to use it:

```
function ajax_fragment(php_file){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        r=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else{ 
        r=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }

    r.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(r.readyState==4 && r.status==200){
            var n = document.createElement("div");       //Create a div to hold the content
            n.className = "feedBox";                     //Give a class 'feddBox' to the div
            n.innerHTML = r.responseText;                //Put the response in the div
            var f = document.createDocumentFragment();   //Create the fragment
            f.appendChild(n);                            //Add the div to the fragment

            //Append the fragment's content to the TOP of wrapper div.
            document.getElementById("wrapper").insertBefore(f, document.getElementById("wrapper").firstChild);
        }
    }
    r.open("GET",php_file,true); 
    r.send();
}
```