# NodeList changes do not affect length

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

i have created a NodeList with `nodeList = document.createDocumentFragment().childNodes;`,

then i have set `nodeList[0] = document.getElementById("foo");`

everything works fine, the only problem is, that `nodeList.length` stays 0

i have allready tried to change an Array to a NodeList. Also i have tried to use a fragment, appended children and changed them afterwards and returned the childnodes.

i cannot just append the original children, because they get removed somewere else then.

what am i missing?

yes i know i could just use an Array, but i want to NodeList element

Comment: "what am i missing?" – There's no way to accomplish that other than the ones you already mentioned you don't want.

Comment: that is very very sad

Comment: ... you could clone the element and appending to the fragment, instead of moving it there. would that be acceptable?

Comment: no because it would be a different one then, it should work like a simple array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use document.createDocumentFragment or document.createElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397161/should-i-use-document-createdocumentfragment-or-document-createelement)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how duplicate works so i will add answer here

from documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocumentFragment DocumentFragment  has child property as read only so you cant write to it, instead use appendChild();

```
var nodeList = document.createDocumentFragment();
nodeList.appendChild(document.getElementById("foo"))
```