# how Document Fragment works?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, documentfragment

Can anyone please explain briefly what documentFragment actually does? I have been searching for a clear explanation but I don't get any until now.

what I read is, documentFragment is something like DOM like structure where we can add modify DOM elements without interrupting the actual flow of the document.

I also read, documentFragment is faster than appending each element into DOM one by one. It felt to me like, documentFragment does not recalculate styles every time so it is faster.

I have two examples,

***DOING IT IN FRAGMENT WAY:***

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
frag.appendChild(div1);
frag.appendChild(div2);
document.getElementById("someId").appendChild(frag);
```

***DOING IT IN NORMAL WAY:***

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(div1);
div.appendChild(div2);

document.getElementById("someId").appendChild(div);
```

**what actually happens in the above two examples?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use document.createDocumentFragment or document.createElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397161/should-i-use-document-createdocumentfragment-or-document-createelement)

Comment: Thanks for the link @EliR. Now got some Idea, of how it works.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's an important difference between "the fragment way" and "the normal way":

#### Using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
document.body.appendChild(div);
console.log(div.childNodes); // logs a NodeList [#text 'Hello', <span>]
```

This results in the following DOM structure:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Hello
    <span></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### Using [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment):

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
frag.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
document.body.appendChild(frag);
console.log(frag.childNodes); // logs an empty NodeList
```

This results in the following DOM structure:

```html
<body>
  Hello
  <span></span>
</body>
```

---

That means that calling `appendChild` or `insertBefore` with an instance of `DocumentFragment` moves the child nodes of the document fragment to the new parent node. After that, the document fragment is empty.

As you have correctly mentioned, it can be more efficient to create a document fragment and append multiple elements to it than to append those elements to the real DOM one by one, causing the browser to re–render parts of the page every time. Because the contents of the document fragment are not visible on screen, the page has to be re–rendered only once.

Whenever you create a large DOM structure, it can be advisable to create it within a document fragment and append that to the DOM when you're done.

Comment: well, I understood what you said above. But I have one last question. In "normal way", is it going to happen multiple rendering processes to append "div" into "someId"?

Comment: No, in that case, there will probably only be one rendering call, and there will be no big difference. `DocumentFragment`s are great if you insert a series of elements.

Comment: Ya! Thank you so much! Now got a clear idea!! @PeterMader

Answer (score 3):

For appending only 2 childs you will not see any performance issue. Imagine that you have an array of books that includes 100 items and you want to append them to the DOM. You would write this code:

```
let books=[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]
let bookList;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',load)
 function load(){
    bookList=document.getElementById('books')
    books.forEach(book=>{
        let li=document.createElement('li')
        li.textContext=book
        li.class="bookItem"
        // here is the headache part
        bookList.appendChild(li)     
    }))
   }
```

So you are going to loop through 100 times and each time, you are going to tell the browser that redraw the screen. This will take up a lot of resources. Depending on the system that you are using, you might see the screen is flickering.

with fragment I would write `load` like this:

```
function load(){
     bookList=document.getElementById('books')
     let df=new DocumentFragment()
     books.forEach(book=>{
         let li=document.createElement('li')
         li.textContext=book
         li.class="bookItem"
         // we are appending to df not to the bookList
         df.appendChild(li)     
    })
    // I collected all list elements inside DocumentFragment
    // Now I append it to the bookList
    bookList.appendChild(df)
  }
```

creating `document fragment` is like creating a `div`. But it does not add any Html to the page. You are not going to see in HTML source code:

```
 <DocumentFragment></DocumentFragment>
```

It is just an empty container that is used to hold other parts of Html. a fragment can be injected and cloned in a single operation instead of having to inject and clone each
individual node over and over again. We are achieving exact same thing with much better performance.