# Which is better to use : doucment fragment or string concatenation while appending html to dom

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I have to append list of cards to dom.

**html**

```
<div class="card">  
   <div class="card-title">Card 1</div>
   <div class="card-subtext">This is card 1</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 let htmlString = '';
 for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
   htmlString += `<div class="card">  
   <div class="card-title">${arr[idx].title}</div>
   <div class="card-subtext">${arr[idx].text}</div>
   </div>`;
 }

 document.getElementByID('card-container').innerHTML = htmlString;
```

where arr is an array of card objects.

It is a good practice to do it this way? (Please note I don't want to use template library).

Or should I use document fragments to achieve the same? If yes, how would it improve the performance?

Comment: I don't think either approach is better than the other -- it boils down to readability and comfort level.  Especially now that there's the new string concatenation, it's a lot cleaner than it was to do string -> HTML than in the past.  I prefer the `document.createElement()` approach, but that's just where my comfort level is

Comment: Note that `<div class="card-title">${arr[idx].title}</div>` could be vulnerable to XSS (if the `title` is coming from user input).

Comment: this is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540613/how-document-fragment-works/70841617#70841617

Answer (score 2):

I suggest one thing above all:

Change the DOM sparingly. For every addition/removal to the DOM invokes a **[reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2549317/2813224)** of the page. The most efficient and fastest way to add elements to the DOM is to create the elements, do all of the necessary modifications and appending *before* adding to the DOM. Then append all of the elements onto a [**DocumentFragment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). Appending the docFrag to the DOM takes one clean addition to the DOM rather than multiple times.

So [`.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) is by far the best as it is demonstrated here at **[jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/dom-reflow)**. Below are 2 demos:

1. **Demo 1** demonstrates the creation of elements [(`.createElement()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), and appending [(`.appendChild()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) them to a **DocumentFragment** (`.createDocumentFragment()`)
2. **Demo 2** demonstrates how to attach a string to a **DocumentFragment** node made by [**`.createContextualFragment()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment).

#### Demo 1

```js
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

var list = document.createElement('ol');
list.className = 'main-list';

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = 'ITEM';
  item.className = 'item'+i;
  list.appendChild(item);
}

frag.appendChild(list);

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

#### Demo 2

```js
var str = `<ol class="main-list"><li class="item0">ITEM</li><li class="item1">ITEM</li><li class="item2">ITEM</li></ol>`;
var node = document.createRange();
var frag = node.createContextualFragment(str);
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldnt worry so much about performance unless you are performing a bazillion of them.

Here are some other threads with more info about this:

[javascript document.createElement or HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182402/javascript-document-createelement-or-html-tags)

And this might help you out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2305677/8004150

(Short: while concatenating, you are rebuilding the whole node, which might be slower)

**Premature optimization is the root of all evil, some may say. Worry about readability, first!**